# Rendering with PDF.js - misprinting issue

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am working on PDF.js and trying to render a pdf on a webpage. I am facing misprinting issue when displaying pdf. You can see that some text is not printed properly
[Bad display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHpxp.png)

However, when I see the pdf in Acrobat, it is displayed perfectly.
[Good Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVin9.png)

Note* - The Pdf contains only text, no images.

I'm using very basic code to display the pdf file

```js
var url = './highlighter_updated.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  
  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    
    var scale = 1.0;
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale});

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem, but only on certain PCs.